# Directly changing default link underline color without CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have to create a page without using a CSS sheet, simply in-line styling. The only internal styles I can have are:

```
<style>
    body {
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    background: url("http://ics.actonhighschool.ca/test/images/fence.jpg"); 
    color: #333333;  /* font color */
    font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    }   
</style>
```

For one of the links I have, this is the code I have:

```
<p>This is the second paragraph. It is also short and boring. Let's create a 
link to the <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp" 
onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='none';
this.style.backgroundColor='#9400d3'; this.style.color='#ffffff';" 
onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='underline';
this.style.color='#3e3e3e'; this.style.backgroundColor='';"><span
style="color: #3e3e3e"> 
HTML Quick Reference List</span></a></p>
```

However, on the page loadup, although the link comes up as the color #3e3e3e, the underline on the link is a different color. After the "onmouseout" event is triggered though, the underline matches the color of the text. How can I fix this without using a style or CSS?

Comment: What color is it showing up as? Maybe we could pull it from the code if we knew what the problem was coming from.

Comment: I don't know exactly? It's not a color that I have set anywhere else that's for sure. How can I check it?

Comment: Not sure how to add the javascript, very new to HTML and coding in general

Comment: http://imgur.com/SFdoFPN    screenshot of the link as it is on loadup

Comment: That is the default, a:visited purple.

Comment: How can I change that? Why does it not change with the font color change in the <span> but it changes with the onmouseout event?

Comment: Because you mouse events are styling the `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the styling to the `<a>` tag, not to the text inside it:

```
<p>This is the second paragraph. It is also short and boring. Let's create a 
link to the <a style="color: #3e3e3e" href="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp" 
onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='none';
this.style.backgroundColor='#9400d3'; this.style.color='#ffffff';" 
onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='underline';
this.style.color='#3e3e3e'; this.style.backgroundColor='';">
HTML Quick Reference List</a></p>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/967z71o6/)

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you... I knew how to do this, I guess coding for 4 hours without rest can screw with your brain.

Comment: I don't get it - it's still CSS - just with javascript...?

Comment: We're not allowed to link to a style sheet basically

Answer (score 0):

This is how to use `css` to do it. You can use this to add the needed styles with `javascript`.

```
a:link {
color: red;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Not allowed to use CSS

Comment: @RunJumpFly, can you explain why you're not allowed to use CSS?  Just out of curiosity.

Comment: Just a challenge for the class I'm taking. We used CSS for the previous assignment, all of our styles have to be in line for this one

Comment: I don't think that's particularly possible unless you're talking about jQuery or inline styles - both of which are essentially applications of CSS.

Comment: Pretty much not allowed to link to a style sheet then. My vocabulary is off, just started learning HTML about... 4 days ago I'd say?

Answer (score 0):

From the picture you posted, **it is the default `a:visited` underline state**, and you aren't catching it in the code you wrote:

Try:

```
a:visited, a:link, a:active {
    color: #3E3E3E
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black
}
```